# Assembly 8086: Converting 8-bit binary number to its Gray number equivalent?

Tags: assembly, gray-code

Problem:

> Write a program to convert an 8-bit binary number entered from the keyboard to the equivalent Gray code binary number, using the following the algorithm:
>
> *[broken image: http://www.harborlandings.com/images/grayAlgm.jpg]*

I'm learning assembly (8086, required by class) and not sure how to do this.

Do I convert each character (1 or 0) as I receive it from the keyboard?  Or, do I read in the entire 8-bit binary number, loop through it, converting as I go?

I come from Perl/Java, so visualizing how this will work in assembly is a bit daunting.  Also, I'm not sure what the symbol is in the algorithm above?

Thank you for your help and critique!

Comment: plus-in-a-circle is the exclusive or (XOR) operator.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any sorts of libraries? Because otherwise getting input will be a real pain in the butt.

Comment: Will you run it in *old* OSes, like DOS?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I've done this the following way...

data segment
     PARLIST LABEL   BYTE
     MAXLEN  DB      40
     ACTLEN  DB      ?
     inpchr  DB      40      DUP(?)
     prmpt   db  '1 or 0: $', 0DH, 0AH,
ends

start:
     mov ax, data
     mov ds, ax
     mov es, ax

     mov bx, 1
     mov cx, 0

Loop1:
  mov     ah, 9
  lea  dx, prmpt
  int  21H

     ; DOS keyboard to enter character
     mov  ah, 0AH
     lea  dx, PARLIST
     int  21H

     ; Move input char to al
 mov al, inpchr

     cmp al, 49  ; Is input char == 1
     jne Loop1

     xor bx, 1 
     jmp Loop1
ends

Comment: That worked :-{  I guess no code in comments!

Comment: I'm running on WinXP, using emulator - http://www.emu8086.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply xor the character with itself shifted right one place to get the Gray representation, no loop needed.  Example when your character is in AL :

```
mov bl, al
shr bl, 1
xor al, bl
```

AL is now the Gray-code representation.

In C this would be :

```
c^=c>>1;
```

To go back to the binary representation you can xor the Gray-code with it self, shifted right by decreasing powers-of-2, starting with the largest power-of-2 which is smaller than the data size, eg:

```
mov bl, al
shr bl, 4
xor al, bl
mov bl, al
shr bl, 2
xor al, bl
mov bl, al
shr bl, 1
xor al, bl
```

In C this would be :

```
c^=c>>4; c^=c>>2; c^=c>>1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been a very long time since I have written any assembly code but the questions seems more philosophical.  Without knowing the larger goals here are some ideas.

Converting every key as they are entered:  Many times the program needs to respond to individual key strokes as the program is running, (ie dynamic commands, up, down, left etc.).  In this case, the key strokes should be converted individually.   Other times, a block of data or strings need to be converted and this operation is usually done at the conclusion of the enter key of is a larger block of data.  These cases require the characters to be “looped” through and converted.

However, in either case the “work” should done in a generic subroutine that can be called from either type of situation.

I hope this helps,

Ed